# Getting Errors while creating new Project in Angular , after removing node-modules and package-lock.json, getting run time errors

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
```

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\kurum\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kurum\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-25T12_48_31_942Z-debug-0.log
Package install failed, see above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove your node_modules folder and package-lock.json first.
Then try this command:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

This command tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway.

Comment: After removing node_modules and package-lock.json and running npm install --legacy-peer-deps
unable to run it, getting other errors

Comment: tell me what errors do you get

Comment: I have added the screen shot of it, can you just look into it and help me

Comment: I am not exactly sure why this happens, but try a few different approaches:
first try: ng serve --open, then try npm install, npm install -g @angular/cli
I hope some of those 3 commands will help